# SP 2013 New List Item with Content Types

Tags: 2013

I am creating a list within SharePoint 2013 and I have a few different content types already created. I would like to have it to where when a user clicks on new it shows them a drop down menu of the different content type choices and they can select from there. Is this possible without some kind of crazy JAVA coding?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint kind of does this out-of-the-box.

If you add multiple content types to a list, you can specify which ones show up in the "New Item" menu on the ribbon:

[image: content types in list settings]

[image: new item ribbon menu]

If the user just clicks on the main part of the ribbon button, or on the "`+ new item`" link on the list view web part, then the default content type for that list will be created.

However, if you go back in and edit the item, you also get a content type selection menu in the edit form:

[image: edit form with content type selection]